# how to connect QActions to SLOTS using qt designer

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I have created a nice looking toolbar using **qt Designer** and populated it with some actions.
I tried to **connect the actions to slots visually from qt designer** by clicking **edit> signals and slots**. This **DID NOT WORK** because i could not find any QAction signals.

**Question.**

Is there a way to connect the QAction SIGNAL(triggered()) to my slots within QT designer?
Please help.
**PS:**
I am currently being forced to connect through code:

```
QObject::connect(myAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(myActionWasTriggered()))
```

but ia am lazy and i wish to connect using qt designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here in Docs [Designer Connection Mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-connection-mode.html)... How to autconnect in the designer

Comment: then you can use the Autoconnect http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6.2/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections ... with your source files

Comment: When i try this on the toolbar, i see only the toolbars signals yet I am trying to connect QActions inside the toolbar to some slots. What i want is to see some actions and their signals within qt designer.

Answer (score 5):

There's "Signal/Slot Editor" docked panel (Toggled with View->Signal/Slot Editor).
You can connect your actions there.
You may also need to add your custom slots via the "Change signals/slots" form context menu.

To save yourself some work, use the auto-connection feature (see [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName)). Basically, all slots named with a specific pattern of `on_objectName_signalName` will be auto-connected.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the "Action editor" panel. You can find it near "Signals & Slots editor".

Answer (score -1):

If you have menu, Please name your actions object according to menus , Suppose you have:

```
File Edit View Tools Help
```

You have 5 menus bar,

So you'll have a set of action_x ,  x is a number.Please naming your x according to your menu.

more explaintion:

```
File = 1
Edit = 2
View = 3
Tools = 4 
Help = 5
```

And suppose :

```
File---> Open ..Close
Edit---> find...replace
View---> ZoomIn ... ZoomOut
Tools--->calender... prefrences
help---> help... about
```

You have 5x2 = 10 , you have 10 action, please manage such as:

```
action_11 == File>Open
action_12 == File>close
action_21 == Edit>find
and so on..
```

Above type of managing make easy your coding .....